# Rate of convergence for 2-D problems

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, rate-of-convergence

How can I generalize the approach of double mesh principle discussed in the [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4430565/the-special-formula-for-order-of-convergence) to 2-D problems like two asset option pricing problem
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=&-\frac{\sigma_{1}^{2} x^{2}}{2} \frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial x^{2}}-\frac{\sigma_{2}^{2} y^{2}}{2} \frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial y^{2}}-\rho \sigma_{1} \sigma_{2} x y \frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial x \partial y}-r x \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}-r y \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}+r u \\
& \text { for }(x, y, t) \in(0, \infty) \times(0, \infty) \times[0, T)
\end{aligned}
$$
with the final payoff condition $u(x, y, T)=\max(K_1-x,K_2-y,0)$ at expiry $T$.

Here, I have the numerical solution $U_{m_1,m_2}^n\sim u(x_{m_1},y_{m_2},t_n),$ where, $x_{m_1}$ and $y_{m_2}$ are spatial points and $t_n$ is the temporal point, after a standard (uniform gridding) finite difference method. To facilitate the numerical method, conventional linear boundary conditions $u(x,y_{min},t)=u(x_{min},y,t)=0,u(x_{max},y,t)=x_{max}$ and, $u(x,y_{max},t)=y_{max}$ have been used.

Further, I am not interested in the error along a spatial line by fixing other spatial variable, Instead, I need the error along the plane at an instant $t=t_0$. Different types of errors are available for me by making use of different matrix norms, but I couldn't find theoretical ROC (rate of convergence).

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need edit your question and add some information. Do you have a parabolic PDE with two spatial variables? Are there any terms involving mixed derivatives, i.e., $u_{xy}$? Is the spatial domain a rectangle or is a more complicated shape. What are the boundary conditions? Are you using a standard scheme such as Crank-Nicolson's method?

Comment: I apologise for the inconvenience, I have tried to reform the post as per your suggestion and hope the question is clear now.

Comment: No apology was needed. By adding the information you have increased  the value of the question and the probability that it can be answered. There is no longer any risk of this question being closed. Is there actually enough information here to solve the problem?  Do you know the values of $u(x,y,T)$ for all $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ or is it just $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}_{+}^2$? Do you have the luxury of choosing the temporal timestep as $\Delta t = \lambda \Delta x^2$ where $\Delta x = \Delta y$ are the stepsizes in the spatial dimensions and $\lambda > 0$ is a constant?

Comment: @CarlChristian conventional linear boundary conditions are used. It is updated in the post. Thnks.

Comment: Also, we have unconditional stability, so mesh parameters are free to be chosen fairly.

Comment: I think that the setup is so smooth that  Richardson extrapolation can work very well. A paper requires my attention right now, but I believe that this answer (https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4355465/307944) to a closely related question will be helpful in your case. Because you can choose $\Delta x  = \Delta y = h$ and $\Delta t = \lambda h^2$ you can reduce a very general asymptotic error expansion into the simple case that is discussed in that answer.